# How to display a function defined message after a successful login or failure

Tags: php

I have a function in my functions.php that uses session to display message whenever record is inserted or could not. My problem is that after the insertion the message does not display even though I started the session in my header.php which is included on the employees.php page and I have also called the message on the same page after setting it in my logic. Below are the codes:

```
else{
//Query to Insert/Add Employees in employees Table
$db->query('INSERT INTO employees(id, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, employeeId, joiningDate, phone, role)VALUES(NULL, :fname, :lname, :username, :email, :password, :employeeId, :joiningDate, :phone, :role)');

//Bind Values to Query Parameters
$db->bindValue(':fname', $c_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':lname', $c_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':username', $c_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':email', $c_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':password', $Hashed_Pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':employeeId', $c_employId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':joiningDate', $c_jdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindValue(':phone', $c_phone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->bindValue(':role', $c_role, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//Query to Check whether Staff Already Exist using Email


//Run Query
$run_employee    = $db->execute();

if($run_employee){

    redirect('employees.php');
    //Closeable Alert Message
    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> Employee Registered Successfully.
        </div>');
}else{
    //Closeable Alert Message
    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Not Successful!</strong> Employee Was Not Registered.
        </div>');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling

```
redirect('employees.php');
```

before setting/displaying the message.

Comment: I think that is not the issue because I have been using this message function always on different bootstrap templates but i have never had this issue. I am suspecting the html tags and the css, may be where i have called the message function

Comment: Switch the order and see if it works.  Do the redirect after keepmsg.

Comment: the php echo is not also displaying anything on page after the insertion of record

Comment: Can you share the entire source code?  It's hard to tell what "keepmsg" is doing without seeing it.